# I try to convert SQLite database to Postgres, I dont know DATETIME equal for postgres database

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, sqldatatypes

I try to convert SQLite database to Postgres, I dont know DATETIME equal for postgres database
Full line is:

```
CREATE TABLE log 
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  date DATETIME,
  msg TEXT
);
```

Comment: look up the available data types [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
> day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
> 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
> as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Taken from https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

But in Postgres you can use **timestamp/timestamptz** datatype which is easily demonstrated over [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/)

Also table code seems to be weird

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

Why are you using primary key and unique together?

You can use below code in Postgres

```
CREATE TABLE log 
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  date timestamp,
  msg TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postgresql's [`DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) which stores also the time.
Also, you could use `VARCHAR(n)` instead of `TEXT` for `msg`'s data type, unless you don't know the max length of the values stored in that column:

```
CREATE TABLE log (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, date DATE, msg VARCHAR(255));
```